# Please help me understand the 'assign' method in the following code

Tags: java, oop

```
class Test { 

    int a, b; 

    Test(int a, int b) {    
        this.a = a; 
        this.b = b; 
    } 

    Test() {               
        a = 0; 
        b = 0; 
    } 

    void print() { 
        System.out.println("A=" + a + ", B=" + b); 
    } 

    void assign(Test ob) {  //How can a class(Test) be passed as an argument in a method?
        this.a = ob.a;      //What does ob.a do?
        this.b = ob.b;      //What does ob.b do?
    }                       //How can a object 'ob' be passed as an argument?
}
```

.

```
class TestDem { 

    public static void main(String ar[]) { 
        Test ob1 = new Test(1, 2); 
        System.out.println("1st object"); 
        ob1.print(); 
        Test ob2 = new Test(); 
        System.out.println("2nd object"); 
        ob2.print(); 
        ob2.assign(ob1); //dont understand how this statement works with the 'assign' method 
        System.out.println("After assigning object 1 to object 2"); 
        System.out.println("1st object"); 
        ob1.print(); 
        System.out.println("2nd object"); 
        ob2.print(); 

    } 
}
```

**Output**

```
1st object
A=1, B=2
2nd object
A=0, B=0
After assigning object 1 to object 2
1st object
A=1, B=2
2nd object 
A=1, B=2
```

Comment: You should read up on the [Java object basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
void assign(Test ob) {  
    this.a = ob.a;      
    this.b = ob.b;      //What does ob.b do?
}
```

This method is similar to the constructor you have used: -

```
public Test(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

- Difference is that, in this method, you are getting the values of `a` and `b` from the reference passed rather than the parameter a, and b itself..
- Also note that it is not a constructor.. It is just assigning the value of passed reference to the current object.. Whereas constructor initializes the instance's state after it is created..

> How can a class(Test) be passed as an argument in a method?

We are **not passing** the **class Test** here, rather, we **are passing** a **reference** to an object of class Test..

This method is doing nothing but creating a copy of the object pointed by that reference (ob in this case).. So, after this method executes, the current object(pointed by `this`) will have the same value as the passed object..

> What does ob.a do?

ob.a refers to the `instance` variable `a` for the reference `ob` of class `Test`, that you passed into this method..

**So, if you have: -**

```
Test ob2 = new Test(1, 2);
Test ob1 = new Test();
ob1.assign(ob2);
```

**Then when this method executes: -**

Since, `this` refers to the current reference, so `this` in method `assign` will refer to `ob1`, since we are calling on this reference..

And, you will have both the reference `ob2` in main method, and `ob` in the parameter of `assign` method pointing to the same object..

So, **ob1.a(this.a)** will be equal to **ob2.a**, and
      **ob1.b(this.b)** will be equal to **ob2.b**

Answer (score 0):

```
void assign(Test ob) {  //How can a class(Test) be passed as an argument in a method?
    this.a = ob.a;      //What does ob.a do?
    this.b = ob.b;      //What does ob.b do?
}                       //How can a object 'ob' be passed as an argument?
```

In Java (apart from primitive types like int, etc. let's not talk about them here) everything extends Object.

You defined a class `Test` that implictely extends `Object`.
This class has two member variables: `a` and `b`, which are of type `int`.

If `ob` is of type `Test`, you can access its members using `ob.a` and `ob.b` (as `a` and `b` are public). And you can set their value using `ob.a = anIntValue` and `ob.b = anIntValue`.

That is what you do in the `assign` method: you pass another object of type `Test` and copy its values into your enclosing object (`this.a = value`, `this.b = value`).

So the result of your method is to modify your internal state by copying the state of an external object.

Answer (score 0):

The method `void assign(Test ob)` takes an object `ob` of type `Test`.  It then assigns the value of `ob`'s `a` value to the class that the method is being called on's `a` value, and then the same for the `b` values.

Perhaps if the method was renamed `copy(Test ob)` it would be clearer what the method does?